# Ubuntu as router with WiFi and Tor

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, tor

Bear with me on this one please

I live in a country with censorship and the government has been shutting down access to certain websites and its thinking about shutting down access to twitter and facebook, as well as other social media sites.

So what I have to work with is this, a WiFi router, an ubuntu box with 2 ethernet connections and my internet router.

This is what I would like to do, to connect the cable modem to my ubuntu box, and then connect my ubuntu box to my wifi router to then give access to all the devices in my house, I was wondering if there was a way to install something like Tor or Vidalia on the ubuntu box and route all blocked traffic through tor so all devices could access the blocked sites without installing tor in every device.

Answer (score 1):

Check out ZenMate for your Chrome/Chromium browser on your PC. 
Tor is a possibility, but I wouldn't trust it because exit nodes can see what you're doing and who you are. You never know. 
If your router supports VPN (OpenVPN) you could invest in a VPN account. There are free accounts but they're usually slow.

Answer from Martin Ravensholt on G+, not myself.

Comment: I will gladly remove my re-posting, if Martin would like to post his answer himself.

Answer (score 0):

Tor is slow, and maybe uneccessary. There are pretty cheap virtual or even dedicated servers for ~ 5€/month,so maybe you could simply tunel traffic through OpenSSH to /from such server. Check for example kimsufi /OVH for cheap dedicated servers, and/or DigitalOcean for virtual servers on SSD storage.

Comment: I can't use that, I can't use anything paid because of government restrictions to pay foreign currency, do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is firmware for your router available that has a Tor enabled option to route all your computers through Tor. Tomato firmware has Tor, however, only traffic on destination port 80 is routed through Tor so it probably won't work for social network sites that use https. DDWRT is probably best for a beginner because the wiki instructions are easy to follow and there's a larger community on the internet. It is possible to brick your router so FOLLOW ALL of the wiki INSTRUCTIONS step by step! It's not complicated, but you should gather all the information for your specific make and model first before starting to prevent problems.  Aftermarket router firmware will also increase router performance, range, speed, etc, considerably. You can check to see of you router is supported here [http://www.ddwrt.com](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database). You will have to do more searching to find out what firmware has the Tor enabled option. After getting familiar with how to flash your firmware using DDWRT you might want to check out firmware from somewhere else.